# Merge two dfs and coalesce the results for nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dfs that have same columns and contain same information, but from different sources:

```
df_orders = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'model':['A1','A3','A6'], 'color':['Red','Blue','Green']})
df_billed = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,6,7],'model':['A1','A7','B1'], 'color':['Purple','Pink','Red']})
```

Then I do a merge left on the df_billed by ids and add suffixes as column names overlap:

```
merge_df = pd.merge(df_billed,df_orders,on='id',how='left',suffixes=('_order','_billed'))
```

Results in

```
     id|model_order|color_order | model_billed | color_billed 
 0   1 |       A1  |    Purple  |         A1   |       Red
 1   6 |       A7  |      Pink  |       NaN    |       NaN
 2   7 |       B1  |       Red  |        NaN   |       NaN
```

The column order has more priority when the suffix is _order than billed, and somehow I would like to have a dataframe where if no billed info, then we take the order, and the suffixes are removed:

```
     id|model_billed | color_billed |
 0   1 |        A1   |      Red     |
 1   6 |        A7   |      Pink    |
 2   7 |        B1   |      Purple  |
```

Ideally I thought of doing a combine_first to coalesce the colums and at the end rename them, but looks a bit dirty in code and looking for another more well-designed solution.

Comment: FYI, your suffixes are flipped. In the merge, you've put `df_billed, df_orders` and then `suffixes=('_order','_billed')`. You can see the _misleading_ results in the merge for `A7` which is actually from `billed` but merge has it under `model_order`.

Comment: You've said _"I would like to have a dataframe where if no billed info, then we take the order"_ - then why doesn't your expected dataframe have A3 and A6 ? Since those are missing in 'billed' but present in 'ordered'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `.fillna()` and use the _order columns to fill the NAs

```
merge_df['model_billed'] = merge_df['model_billed'].fillna(merge_df['model_order'])
merge_df['color_billed'] = merge_df['color_billed'].fillna(merge_df['color_order'])
```

### Output

```
merge_df[['id', 'model_billed', 'color_billed']]
    id  model_billed    color_billed
0   1   A1              Red
1   6   A7              Pink
2   7   B1              Red
```

### UPDATE

If there are more such columns, you can just use a loop like this:

```
col_names = ['model', 'color']
for col in col_names:
    merge_df[col+'_billed'] = merge_df[col+'_billed'].fillna(merge_df[col+'_order'])
```

Comment: That looks good but what when there were more columns? Is there a way to make it so I don't need one line of code per column? Otherwise is almost exactly the same as using combine_first